# Why is this question regarded as opinion based?

Tags: discussion

So [Why do people tend to think anime is weird porno?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/31063/why-do-people-tend-to-think-anime-is-weird-porno) got closed as opinion based.

Personally I don't consider this to be opinion based, as the question states

> Is there a specific reason as to why this stereotyping came to be?

Which as far as I believe could be backed up by facts. The comment by Toshinou also seems to hint to this.

So, why is it considered opinion based?

Comment: Something tells me this opinion of anime as being just porn comes from watching scandalous news reports on tv about how "perverted japanese cartoons make people into weirdos". That's not my opinion, btw, it's the reality. Potential answerers can probably find hard info on such misconceptions, so the question should be reopened.

Comment: I voted to close, and I confess I did so without strong conviction. The wording of the title sounded really naive, and you started by bringing up that "summarize Sword Art Online for my mom" question that I hated. It seemed like a question that was going to attract a lot of whining and ranting instead of good answers. But the question is open again, and Toshinou-san's answer is really good, so I admit I was wrong and the people who reopened it were right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that most close votes were coming based on the title of the question, and the lower quality question I linked within it. And not specifically for it being opinion based.

The question has been re-opened.